# Direct sum of $Row(A)$ and solution space $Ax=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a real matrix of order $n\times n$.
Is it possible to prove that the vector space of the solutions $Ax = 0$ and $Row(A)$ (vector space of span of rows A) are direct sum of $\mathbb{R}^n$ ?

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: yes.

Consider the $n × n$ matrix $A$ and denote with $R_i$ the $i$ row. Suppose $v\in \ker(A)$. We have:
$$R_1\cdot v=0\,\,\land\,\, R_2\cdot v=0\,\,\dots\,\,R_n\cdot v=0$$
So, the vector $v$ is ortogonal to all $R_i$.

**Theorem.** Let $V$ an euclidean space and $W$ one of its subspace, then $W$ and $W^{\perp}$ are indipendent and:
$$V=W\bigoplus W^{\perp}$$

So, $\ker(A)\perp R$ and, by the last theorem: $$\bar{\mathbb{R}}^n=\ker(A)\bigoplus R$$